# Follow-up question on sitting in a train with closed eye, this time only using force sense in a suddenly accelerated train

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, everyday-life

[This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/711352/) very interesting question inspired me to ask a follow-up question.

We sit on a comfortable chair in a smoothly rolling train. There are no bumps to be felt. There is no wind to be felt either. We are blindfolded and ear-plugged.

Then the train suddenly accelerates. Can we feel if the acceleration is positive or negative? We have no idea what direction we go before the break is applied.

Comment: Since, this is a follow up to another post I have a suggestion.  The heart of this problem is simply is how much information is required to determine orientation on a moving train and which senses are responsible for receiving that information. If your question could be rephrased I think it would be a better follow up.

Answer (score 2):

If the chair is oriented such that we are facing the direction of the original velocity of the train (without knowing it) and the acceleration increases the speed of the train (positive acceleration) then you will be pushed back in the back of the chair. If the train brakes (negative acceleration) then we will feel like we are falling forward in the chair.

Since this is obviously reversed relative of what we would experience if we were sitting the other way in the chair (without knowing), there is no way to distinguish the two scenarios by "feeling" only.

Comment: And what if the train comes to full stop?

Comment: With respect to what frame? ;) The train is already at rest with respect to the chair.

Comment: WRT to the rails frame. Is there something different in s full stop?

Comment: In reality, my experience is that the train makes a "wobble" when it comes to a complete stop, because the frame of the train still has some velocity when the wheels end up stopping. But whether the acceleration *actually* changes sign during this wobble, or if it just changed value as $v$ goes to zero I cannot say.

Comment: Exactly! The wobble! I see what you mean. You accelerate slightly opposite.